# SQL query for search and update column

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the syntax for a query to:

Search a table for all rows with a substring X within a certain column, 
and replace the column in all the rows found with substring X removed.

Basically, I need to remove html tags that snuck into title sections.

Comment: How is this too broad? Barmar answered the question perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `REPLACE()` function in an `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET title = REPLACE(title, 'substringX', '');
```